# Unable to access some Sharepoint Online sites using Java graph API

Tags: java, sharepoint, permissions, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying use Graph API in Java to do few operations in a site. I am able to see all sites in our organization except for the few. I am using app-only authentication and have given "site.FullControl.All" permission.

Any pointers ?

The code used is given below

```
      ClientSecretCredential  _clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
              .clientId(clientid)
              .tenantId(tenantid)
              .clientSecret(clientsecret)
              .build();

      final TokenCredentialAuthProvider authProvider =
              new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(
                  // Use the .default scope when using app-only auth
                  List.of("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"), _clientSecretCredential);

      GraphServiceClient _appClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
              .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
              .buildClient();

    List<Site> sites2 = new ArrayList<Site>();
    SiteCollectionPage siteCollectionPage = _appClient.sites().buildRequest().get();
    List<Site> sites = siteCollectionPage.getCurrentPage();
```

The list return some of the sites but not all sites. I tried to access the site with SiteId but unable to find site , getting  itemNotFound exception

Comment: So, some sites are not even accessible directly by calling /sites/{site_id}? Are the sites in different geo?

Comment: Yes. All in same geo.